# Maven Properties List

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

Despite the title, I'm not looking for a list of properties to use with Maven.

I wish to set up a profile that contains a list of items, in this case a server list.  A local dev profile will have just a single server whereas for testing there could be one, two or more.

How can I write a list of items that are basically 'the same thing'?

```
<profile>
    <id>DEV_COMMON</id>
    <properties>
        <kafka.config.retries>3</kafka.config.retries>
        <kafka.brokers> <!-- the following causes Maven error -->
            <server>
                <host>hostname1</host>
                <port>1234</port>
            </server>
            <server>
                <host>secondhostname</host>
                <port>5678</port>
            </server>
            <server>
                <host>hostnameNumber3</host>
                <port>9101</port>
            </server>
        </kafka.brokers>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

The profile above produces the error:

```
TEXT must be immediately followed by END_TAG and not START_TAG
```

Assistance greatly appreciated.
KA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the properties in Maven (AFAIK) do not allow repeatibility of values, because each property can be accessed just by name:

`${test.server}`

... So you wouldn't be able to access other properties than the first. That's why Maven does not even allow sub-nodes within the `properties` node.

As a lesser evil, I'd give these properties an unique name:

```
<properties>
    <kafka.broker.server1.host>hostname1</kafka.broker.server1.host>
    <kafka.broker.server1.port>1234</kafka.broker.server1.port>
    <kafka.broker.server2.host>hostname2</kafka.broker.server2.host>
    <kafka.broker.server2.port>1235</kafka.broker.server2.port>
</properties>
```

Comment: After investigation I suspected as much
Thanks for the confirmation.